# Check if an object has an attribute from a list of attributes, and if is found assign it to a variable - dynamic

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-object

I check if an object has an attribute or another, can have only one.

If the attribute is found, assign his value to a variable. Can this be done dynamic(the attributes number can variate), getting from a list of possible attributes ?

```
if hasattr(o, 'a') or if hasattr(o, 'b') or if hasattr(o, 'c') or if hasattr(o, 'd'):

result = the one that exist
```

Comment: `result = next((getattr(obj, attr) for attr in attributes if hasattr(obj, attr), None)`, here `attributes` is your list of attributes. If none are found, `result` will be `None` (you might want to use another value to signify an empty result).

Comment: `break` is your friend:


    for attr in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']:
        if hasattr(o, attr):
            variable = attr
            break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the attributes into a list and iterate through it:

```
for attr in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']:
    try:
        result = getattr(o, attr)
    except AttributeError:
        # Try the next one
        continue
    break
else:
    raise ValueError("No attribute found")
```

Apparently, the list can also be constructed dynamically.